# Strange 5% product price discount in zen cart

Tags: php, mysql, zen-cart

Zen Cart v1.3.9.h

We noticed two strange orders recently:
the product price got 5% discount in the orders_total.

We didn't set any discount to the product, to the customer,
or to the customer group, or any coupon.

We set MySQL general log before, so checked mysql.log and MySQL database:

1. Product price is ok, not changed.
2. Data inserted into table orders_products is ok, the product price is the right price
3. Product price got 5% off and inserted into table orders_total.

All we could find some clues is the SQLs in mysql.log:

```
INSERT INTO orders (..., order_total, ...) VALUES (..., '95', ...);
INSERT INTO orders_total (orders_id, title, text, value, class, sort_order) VALUES (..., '95', 'ot_subtotal', ...)
INSERT INTO orders_products (orders_id, products_id, products_model, products_name, products_price, final_price, ...) VALUES (..., '100.0000', '100', ...)
```

Product price is 100, data inserted into orders_products table is OK.
But the problem is that in orders table and in orders_total table the product price changed to 95!

The order with product price 5% off, we can't redo it.
So we don't know how to debug it.
It just happened that once or two.

Any clue how to debug this kind of strange things?

Comment: I am pretty sure it's an exploit. You were probably compromised with some kind of SQL or XSS vulnerability. I am not sure about this but I highly suspect that part of your purchase portal has un-patched vulnerabilities.

Comment: We also thinked about exploit, but why just 95%? 5% off is not so much. if it's a exploit why don't set more discount.

Comment: I don't understand. You just said — 'got 95% discount in the orders_total.'

Comment: Updated my question to add some SQLs getting from mysql.log, hope that can be more clear. @flippex17

Comment: From previous painful experience 1.3.9 is way out of date and is insecure as hell and there are compromises all over the place so I would strongly advise upgrading regardless of whether it is the cause of this or not